# Determine the person with the fewest entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

That seems to be quite simple, but there is no solution right now. I would like to determine from a table the person who has the least entries. If there are several, I just want to limit it to TOP 1.

In this example it would be Person 2 (or Person 5) with the least entries.

```
Id, Person
1, Person 1
2, Person 3
3, Person 4
4, Person 1
5, Person 1
6, Person 3
7, Person 2
8, Person 5
9, Person 6
```

Comment: What about `Person 4`, `Person 6`? it has only 1 entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`:

```
select top (1) person
from t
group by person
order by count(*);
```

The question specifically asks for *one* row in the result set.  If you want all of them, then use `top (1)` with ties`.

Comment: what if there are many people with the same number of entries?

Comment: Add `WITH TIES` @kristjanKica

Comment: @KristjanKica . . . The question specifically asks for 1 row.

Comment: True a "person" is a single person, not many. The quesion should say "people" if you want all the relevant ones.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 person
FROM mytable
GROUP BY person
ORDER BY COUNT(*), person
```

This will give you a unique record with the name of the person that has fewest entries. If there are ties, the person with the alphabetically first name will show up.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=daafc248d95e159f4a34da5aeb07830a)** with your sample data:

```
| person   |
| :------- |
| Person 2 |
```

Comment: is there Limit in sql server?

Comment: You want `TOP`, `LIMIT` doesn't exist in T-SQL.

Comment: @Larnu Or maybe `OFFSET` and `FETCH` on 2012+ versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
SELECT TOP 1  Person -- You can add WITH TIES too
FROM
(
  SELECT Person, COUNT(Person) Cnt
  FROM
  (
    VALUES
    (1, 'Person 1'),
    (2, 'Person 3'),
    (3, 'Person 4'),
    (4, 'Person 1'),
    (5, 'Person 1'),
    (6, 'Person 3'),
    (7, 'Person 2'),
    (8, 'Person 5'),
    (9, 'Person 6')
  ) T(ID, Person)
  GROUP BY Person
) TT
ORDER BY Cnt;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9bcf8733d6a1d47bfd1340049b8dfce9)**

---

You could also use `OFFSET` and `FETCH`if you have 2012+ version as

```
SELECT Person
FROM
(
  SELECT Person, COUNT(Person) Cnt
  FROM
  (
    VALUES
    (1, 'Person 1'),
    (2, 'Person 3'),
    (3, 'Person 4'),
    (4, 'Person 1'),
    (5, 'Person 1'),
    (6, 'Person 3'),
    (7, 'Person 2'),
    (8, 'Person 5'),
    (9, 'Person 6')
  ) T(ID, Person)
  GROUP BY Person
) TT
ORDER BY Cnt
OFFSET 0 ROWS  
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```