# Determine the person with the fewest entries (2)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to select from a table the person who has the least entries. If there are several, I just want to limit it to TOP 1.

In this example it would be Person 2 (or Person 5) with the least entries.

```
Table 1:

Id, Person
1, Person 1
2, Person 3
3, Person 4
4, Person 1
5, Person 1
6, Person 3
7, Person 2
8, Person 5
9, Person 6
```

Now, it's getting more tricky. There is a second table with all persons listed.

```
Table 2:

Person
Person 1
Person 3
Person 4
Person 5
Person 6
Person 7
```

The query should consider this table too and output "Person 7" (Because it has 0 entries in Table 1)

On the other hand, if Person 2 and Person 7 were not in Table 2, the query should output Person 5 (the least entries in Table 1 and exists in Table 2). I hope that it is reasonably understandable.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are asking the same question from an hour ago?

Comment: It's not the same question. It is more complex than the other one. And someone deleted an answser to it. Thanks god I spotted it before it got deleted.

Comment: Here is the fiddle to the answer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aeb8d2ff6415def36800f985b759a769

Comment: No idea who answered, but thanks mate!

Comment: Please undo your action, this is not the same question. read again. The info "This question already has an answer here" is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach would be aggregation along with `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1     -- use TOP 1 WITH TIES to get all ties
    t2.Person,
    COUNT(t1.Person) AS cnt
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t2.Person = t1.Person
GROUP BY
    t2.Person
ORDER BY
    COUNT(t1.Person);
```

### Demo

We left join from the reference table to the table containing the counts, counting a column from the latter table.  This ensures that people with zero counts (e.g. Person 7) do not get filtered off.

Comment: Instead of answering [dups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57936301/6426692) you should cast a CV.